# Surface-dependency of kinetic in speed law?

Tags: kinetics, solid-state-chemistry

we can comprehend the quantitative dependency of the kinetic of a chemical reaction through the speed law: $v(t) = k \cdot c(...)^k \cdot c(...)^n$

Here I used the concentration $c$ for    that take place in aqueous phases. For the gas phase, I can use $v(t) = k \cdot p(...)^k \cdot p(...)^n $ All is fine, moreover I can convert $p$ into $c$ through $pV=nRT$

But what is with solid-solid reaction? Here the "reaction surface" is the crucial key word. But how can I express this in the speed law which I written above for aqueous and gas reaction? Or is this impossible for solid-solid reaction in this way?

Thank for your answers!

Comment: The expression you want will depend on [surface concentration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactions_on_surfaces), normally in m$^{-2}$.
In practice the processes of adsorption of the reactants and desorption of products are also important and those are dependent on the surface area of the catalyst and the bulk concentrations (in solvent/solid surface heterogeneous catalysis) or partial pressure (in gas/solid surface heterogeneous catalysis).